# How do I reinstall Windows Store games?

Tags: windows-10, sea-of-thieves

The game I'm specifically asking about is Sea of Thieves.  After the most recent update, my game softlocks any time I open the map radial (even after restarting the game and restarting my computer).  This obviously makes the game impossible to play single-player and very teammate-reliant when playing with a crew.  I'd like to reinstall the game to see in hopes that it fixes the issue.

But it doesn't seem like there's any way to do it!  If I open the game hub in the windows store, the only option is "play".  There is no "uninstall", and no "repair installation".  I could try to find and delete the files on my computer, but I've read [horror stories](https://www.seaofthieves.com/forum/topic/27587/unable-to-reinstall/4) on the forums that removing the game can be a one-way trip.  How can I repair my installation/reinstall a Windows App game?

Comment: Uninstalling it using the *add/remove programs* tool in windows settings is no option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to do this a few nights ago and the option to uninstall wasn't in the Windows store either. I had to open my control panel, go to Add/Remove programs and uninstall it from there. Was able to reinstall it after this :)

Comment: This was indeed the proper path to reinstalling the game!  Though I should note that after redownloading the 20GB game, this particular issue still persisted.  I was able to fix it by [resetting by keybindings to default](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/331395/96435).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to using the Add/Remove programs control panel, you can also uninstall Windows Store Apps from the context menu accessed by right clicking on their icon in the start menu:

[image: Right-click menu]

This will give you a simple prompt to uninstall the app:

[image: Windows Store Uninstall]

Or if it's not a Windows Store App will take you to the original Add/Remove Programs control panel.