# How do I stop my radials from softlocking the game?

Tags: sea-of-thieves

After the most recent update, I've been having a completely game-breaking issue.  Whenever I open the map radial (which I rebound to F), the game softlocks.  I can't select a map or close the radial, though I can still walk around (the camera is frozen though because the mouse is supposed to control the menu).  If I open the escape menu, I can no longer move or perform any action and I have to close and reopen the game.

This makes the game entirely unplayable as all quests require voyage information.  I was able to play just fine before, but now even uninstalling and reinstalling the game doesn't fix it.  What can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem occurs when you rebind a radial to the `F` key or `X` button on an Xbox controller.  [The dev team is aware of this issue](https://support.seaofthieves.com/hc/en-gb/articles/360001069048-Radial-UI-menu-stuck-on-screen), though they didn't fix it in the most recent patch.

You can fix the issue by unbinding that specific key/button or by **resetting the button configurations to default** (Settings -> Keyboard and Mouse/Controller -> Reset to Default).

**EDIT**: This issue has been addressed in the 1.0.6 patch for the game.  If you encounter this issue, you should **update your game** using the Microsoft store.

Comment: This appears to have been addressed with the [latest patch](https://www.seaofthieves.com/release-notes).